# ASP.NEt Web API and Elmah

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I am developing a Web API application. I have followed the Elmah setup. However when I want to have access to the log file by browsing to the url on my local machine I got the following error:

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://api.smsgh.local/elmah.axd'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'elmah.axd'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Please assit me solving this.

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you remember to add the http handler processing the request for /elmah.axd?

Answer (score 1):

you need to tell the routing configuration to ignore *.axd:

`routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");`